# Intellij Pycharm: Display Plugins by Installation Time

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-plugin

In Intellij Pycharm: how can I sort the installed plugins by installation time?

Background: since the installation of some plugins, the CPU consumption of Pycharm is significantly higher.

Before I begin to dig into the analysis of the threaddump feature of the CPU plugin, I simply want to uninstall the latest plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is read this:

[Plugin directory location](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

For example, for me the location is:

`~/.IntelliJIdea2017.3/config/plugins`

You can sort files by `last modified` date and see which one was installed most recently.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful
For the moment, I uninstalled: .PyCharm2017.3/config/plugins/pysynthetic-intellij 
.PyCharm2017.3/config/plugins/python-profiler-experimental
.PyCharm2017.3/config/plugins/robot-plugin. The plugin .PyCharm2017.3/config/plugins/PythonDCE does not appear in the plugin list but in the file system you mentioned

Comment: I will observe it for some time and tell you later + accept your answer. Thanks. PythonDCE = Inspections for detecting potentially dead code and intentions for generating boilerplate code. Removed.

Comment: Thanks, let me know if usage improves.